# How do you update model from directive in Angular 2?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular, datepicker

How do I update my model upon change from Jquery Datepicker? If I manually type into the `<input>` the model updates, but the model doesn't update after making a selection from the Jquery Datepicker popup. The `<input>` value updates with the selected date, but the model doesn't change.

I've tried wrapping the datepicker() in a timeout, but that doesn't work either. How can I make the model aware of the change in the directive?

Input in Component Template:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="foreigndate" datepicker>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[datepicker]'
})
export class DatePickerDirective {
  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    $(el.nativeElement).datepicker();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[(ngModel)]` updates `foreigndate` when `input` is fired which seems not to be the case when datepicker updates the value.

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ doesn't provide any information about events fired when the value changes.

If it would you could use this workaround

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="foreigndate" datepicker (someEvent)="foreigndate=$event.target.value">
```

Listening to the `change` event this way might be worth a try.

Otherwise this should work

```
<input #datepicker type="text" class="datepicker" [(ngModel)]="foreigndate" datepicker>
```

```
@ViewChild('datepicker') datePicker:ElementRef;

ngDoCheck() {
  this.foreigndate = this.datePicker.nativeElement.value;
}
```

Comment: @Gunter Can you please provide sample plunkr code. It would help us.

Comment: What about you provide a Plunker that demonstrates where you're stuck and I have a look to get it fixed? ;-)